# predict value from a non parametric model in R

Tags: r, regression

The target is to predict the values to the test set with the package monreg model, but this si not working with the predict function, because there isn't a model object to use the prediction function.

Giving an example:

```
require(monreg)   # Package ‘monreg’ 
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x + rnorm(100)

x_train=x[0:80]
y_train=y[0:80]
x_test=x[81:100]
y_test=y[81:100]

mon1 <- monreg(x, y, hd = .5, hr = .5)

# I was expecting to get the prediction over the test partion as R usualy works
predict(mon1,h=length(y_test))
```

But this is not working. **In the case this package doesnt have any predict function, I would accept any advice to implement the Narayada Watson regression in R in order to predict values like this example I gave.**

Comment: I think out of sample prediction is not possible with `monreg`.  I can only think of this workaround. Add theoretical limiting values of `x` and corresponding `y` values.  Set `t` to some high number. Find close values of your `x_test` quantiles in `z`. Find close `estimation` of that `z`.

Comment: @Lstat , thanks for your response, any other non parametric regression package to predict  Narayada Watson models or another type like them?

Comment: Nothing comes to my mind now. Maybe people on CrossValidated can help.